# If $T(x,y,z)=x^2+y+az^3$ and the max rate of change at $(1,1,1)$ is $3$ times the rate in the $y$-direction, what is $a$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that the temperature T in R^3 is given by T(x,y,z)=x^2+y+az^3.Find the constant a so that the maximum rate of change of T at P(1,1,1) equals three times the rate at which T is changing in the y direction

I know the maximum rate of change is in the direction of the gradient T and the rate of change is |gradient T|

And i know the rate of change of temperature in the y direction is given by the directional derivative DyT=(j)(gradient T)

Looking for some help with this exam review question.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the rate of change in the $y$ direction is $T_y(x,y,z) = 1$. The gradient is $(2x, 1, 3az^2)$, which is $(2, 1, 3a)$ when you plug in $(1,1,1)$.

So we want $|(2,1,3a)| = \sqrt{4 + 1 + 9a^2} = 3$. Solving for $a$ we get $a^2 = 9 - 4 - 1 = 4 \implies a = \pm 2$.

Comment: After squaring and rearranging, you should have $9a^2=9-4-1$.